# Живой поиск имени клиента при добавлении заказа

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Есть две базы.

1. Клиенты
2. Заказы
   При добавлении заказа, есть поле Имя клиента (**client_name**), которое нужно брать из первой базы (также же **client_name**). 
   При введении первых букв имени клиента, выводится список. Выбираю нужное имя и оно вставляется в мой input (**referal**), но почему-то при добавлении в базу что-то идет не так и оно остается пустым в MySQL, другие поля нормально добавляются. Где моя ошибка?

**Input**

```js
<label>Имя и Фамилия Клиента</label>
<input type="text" name="referal" class="who form-control" autocomplete="off">
<ul class="search_result"></ul>
```

**search.js**

```js
$(function(){
    
    //Живой поиск
    $('.who').bind("change keyup input click", function() {
        if(this.value.length >= 2){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: "search.php", //Путь к обработчику
                data: {'referal':this.value},
                response: 'text',
                success: function(data){
                    $(".search_result").html(data).fadeIn(); //Выводим полученые данные в списке
                }
            })
        }
    })
    
    $(".search_result").hover(function(){
        $(".who").blur(); //Убираем фокус с input
    })
    
    //При выборе результата поиска, прячем список и заносим выбранный результат в input
    $(".search_result").on("click", "li", function(){
        s_user = $(this).text();
        $(".who").val(s_user).attr('disabled', 'disabled'); //деактивируем input, если нужно
        $(".search_result").fadeOut();
    })

})
```

**search.php**

```html
$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
$mysqli -> query("SET NAMES 'utf8'") or die ("Ошибка соединения с базой!");

if(!empty($_POST["referal"])){
$db_table = "clients"; 
    $referal = trim(strip_tags(stripcslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST["referal"]))));

    $db_referal = $mysqli -> query("SELECT * from ".$db_table." search WHERE client_name LIKE '%$referal%'")
    or die('Ошибка №'.__LINE__.'<br>Обратитесь к администратору сайта пожалуйста, сообщив номер ошибки.');

    while ($row = $db_referal -> fetch_array()) {
        echo "\n<li>".$row["client_name"]."</li>"; 
    }
}
```

**Обработчик добавления заказов, то есть после выбора нужного клиента**

```html
$client_name = $_POST["referal"];
$db_table = "orders"; // Имя Таблицы БД
     
    // Подключение к базе данных
    $db = mysql_connect($host,$user,$password) OR DIE("Не могу создать соединение ");     
    // Выборка базы
    mysql_select_db("crm",$db);
     
    // Установка кодировки соединения
    mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'",$db);
     
    $result = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO ".$db_table." (client_name,status,date) VALUES ('$client_name','$status','$date')");
```

Comment: Вывод добавьте вниз вопроса `"INSERT INTO ".$db_table." (client_name,status,date) VALUES ('$client_name','$status','$date')"` - результирующую строку.

Comment: @AlexanderBragin не совсем понял о чем вы

Comment: Ну вы вывод добавьте SQL-запроса, чтобы посмотреть все ли данные поставляются и как. `echo "INSERT INTO ".$db_table." (client_name,status,date) VALUES ('$client_name','$status','$date')";`

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался)

Comment: Я думаю имеет смысл использовать input совместно с datalist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Заменил

```
$(".who").val(s_user).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

на

```
$(".who").val(s_user)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#myTable tr").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: добавьте чуть больше информации о том, как работает предложенный вами код и отформатируйте его.